# Android - WebView moveTaskToBack to go back to the previous page

Tags: android, browser

Is it possible to use the soft button to go back to previous web page?

I know that when we use the android's normal internet App, the button is functioning properly.

However when I implement a simple app arranged WebView for the web surfing purpose, the soft button only works as a app shutting down operation not going to previous web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, there kindly is a function named **goBack();**